# Separate orderer for each organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I want to have orderer **beside each organization** and NOT to create a separate organization for orderers. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the application organizations can provide ordering nodes. For example the [sample configuration](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/sampleconfig/configtx.yaml#L65) shows a single organization providing both peers and ordering nodes. Simply configure OrdererEndpoints under the organization configuration.

That being said, for each organization that provides an ordering node, you may want to consider creating a separate logical organization in the channel configuration, so that the peer credentials and orderer credentials can be managed separately using different root certificate authorities.

Comment: I could separate the orderers, now I want to use an api service to register a user and add the car to my chaincode, I can register the user successfully, but for adding car I got this following error:
`Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
Unable to connect to the discovered orderer orderer1.org2.example.com:10050 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer1.org2.example.com:10050, url:grpcs://orderer1.org2.example.com`

it is same for other orderers too